# An issue with a character in Kazakh case insensitive collations

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have an issue with Сyrillic characters 'E' and 'e' which should be equal when a case insensitive collation is used. And that is correct for all collations apart from the Kazakh ones.

I checked all CI collations using a query below:

```
SELECT 'DECLARE @Test_' + name + ' TABLE (
    Code nvarchar(32) COLLATE ' + name + '
)

INSERT @Test_' + name + ' (Code)
VALUES (N''Е''), (N''е'')

SELECT ''' + name + ''', * FROM @Test_' + name + ' WHERE Code = N''Е'' COLLATE ' + name 

FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE name LIKE '%CI%'
```

Two rows are returned as expected for all collations but not Kazakh.

Sample query to illustrate the issue:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Code nvarchar(32) COLLATE Kazakh_90_CI_AS
);

DECLARE @UpperChar  nchar(1) = N'Е';
DECLARE @LowerChar  nchar(1) = N'е';

SELECT  ASCII(@UpperChar) AS 'UpperChar ASCII', ASCII(@LowerChar) AS 'LowerChar ASCII';

/* Just ASCII-codes for the chars

UpperChar ASCII LowerChar ASCII
--------------- ---------------
197             229
*/

INSERT @Test (Code)
VALUES (@UpperChar), (@LowerChar);

SELECT DISTINCT Code AS 'DISTINCT Code' FROM @Test;

/* Should be one row with CI collation - FALSE

DISTINCT Code
--------------------------------
Е
е
*/

SELECT Code AS 'Code = @UpperChar'
FROM @Test
WHERE Code = @UpperChar;

/* Should be two rows with CI collation - FALSE

Code = @UpperChar
--------------------------------
Е
*/

SELECT Code AS 'Code = @LowerChar'
FROM @Test 
WHERE Code = @LowerChar;

/* Should be two rows with CI collation - FALSE

Code = @LowerChar
--------------------------------
е
*/

SELECT Code AS 'Code = @UpperChar OR Code = LOWER(@UpperChar)'
FROM @Test
WHERE Code = @UpperChar
    OR Code = LOWER(@UpperChar);

/*Check LOWER('Е') = 'е'  - TRUE

Code = @UpperChar OR Code = LOWER(@UpperChar)
---------------------------------------------
Е
е
*/

SELECT Code AS 'Code = @LowerChar OR Code = UPPER(@LowerChar)'
FROM @Test 
WHERE Code = @LowerChar
    OR Code = UPPER(@LowerChar);

/*Check UPPER('е') = 'Е' - TRUE

Code = @LowerChar OR Code = UPPER(@LowerChar)
---------------------------------------------
Е
е
*/
```

Other Сyrillic characters behave as expected.

What could I perform to fix the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before we get into the specifics, here are two things that would help in general:

- The `ASCII()` function is meant for `VARCHAR` data and is sensitive to the code page associated with the collation of the data (for variables it's the current database's default collation). But in this case, we are only dealing with Unicode / `NVARCHAR` data, so the `UNICODE()` function should be used instead.
- When working with characters having ASCII values / code points above 127, it's helpful to have the script create the specific character(s) using either the `CHAR()` or `NCHAR()` functions. This makes the script more transportable as there won't be character conversion issues when opening/pasting the script into an environment that doesn't support certain characters. And, it makes the script more readable / understandable as there won't be confusion for readers when working with characters that look like other characters but are in fact different (such as the ones we are dealing with here).

**Now, a little bit of background first so that the explanation will make sense:**

Unicode sorting / comparison is done by assigning multiple weights to each character. Two of the weight categories are case and diacritic (i.e. accents). Having multiple categories makes it easier to deal with the various combinations of Case Sensitive vs Insensitive and Accent Sensitive vs Insensitive. Most (if not all) defined characters have default sort weights. These default weights can be overridden by culture-specific values when using a specific culture / locale. When using US English, the defaults are used (i.e. no overrides). This is why characters from other languages still often sort correctly (or mostly correctly) even when using a `Latin1_General` collation, and why US English will still work correctly when using a `Hebrew` (or `Japanese`, etc) collation (because the `Hebrew` collation doesn't override the US English characters' weights).

The various weights for each character are maintained in a file. Upper-case and lower-case mappings are in a separate file. And, while the Unicode Consortium has gotten into the rhythm of updating yearly, Microsoft does so far less frequently. Based on their [publicly available sort weight files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10921), they only have the following versions (for Windows):

1. Windows NT 4.0 through Windows Server 2003
2. Windows Vista
3. Windows Server 2008
4. Windows 7 and Windows server 2008 R2
5. Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012
6. Windows 10

SQL Server has fewer versions:

1. Collations without a version number in their name are version "80" (i.e. introduced in SQL Server 2000)
2. Collations with `_90_` in their name were introduced in SQL Server 2005
3. Collations with `_100_` in their name were introduced in SQL Server 2008
4. Collations with `_140_` in their name were introduced in SQL Server 2017 (sadly, the only collations with this version are the Japanese collations)

Finally, please keep in mind that the SQL Server collations are *based on*, but are not identical to, the Windows collations. I believe that the version 100 collations are associated with the "Windows Server 2008" file, while the version 80 and 90 collations should be most closely associated with the "Windows NT 4.0 through Windows Server 2003" file (since Vista was released in 2007).

**With all of that in mind:**

Just so there's no confusion for anyone reading this: the characters in question here are "Cyrillic Capital Letter Ie: Е" and "Cyrillic Small Letter Ie: е" (Unicode code points U+0415 and U+0435, respectively), which *look* identical to the Latin characters "E" and "e", but are definitely different. For example:

```sql
SELECT  NCHAR(0x0415) AS [Cyrillic Capital Letter Ie],
        NCHAR(0x0045) AS [Latin Capital Letter E],
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0415) = NCHAR(0x0045) COLLATE Kazakh_100_CI_AI,
            '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh],
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0415) = NCHAR(0x0045) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI,
            '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General]
```

returns:

```
Cyrillic Capital Letter Ie    Latin Capital Letter E    Kazakh    Latin1_General
Е                             E                         <>        <>
```

The default behavior across all of the Microsoft sort weight files is that these two characters are the same except for their case. This is why they compare as equal in all case-insensitive collations except for the `Kazakh` collations.

Why do these two characters — U+0415 and U+0435 — compare as different when using case-insensitive Kazakh collations? Because (and for whatever reason), both the "Windows NT 4.0 through Windows Server 2003" and the "Windows Server 2008" sort weight files contain an override for U+0435 ("Cyrillic Small Letter Ie: е") when using the Kazakh culture. The override makes this characater, U+0435, equate to the following characters (and a few others):

```sql
-- case-sensitive
SELECT  NCHAR(0x0435) AS [Cyrillic Small Letter Ie], -- е
        NCHAR(0x04bf) AS [Cyrillic Small Letter Abkhasian Che With Descender], -- ҿ
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x04bf) COLLATE Kazakh_90_CS_AI, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_90], -- =
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x04bf) COLLATE Kazakh_100_CS_AI, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_100], -- =
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x04bf) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General], -- =
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x04bf) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General_100] -- <>

-- accent-sensitive
SELECT  NCHAR(0x0435) AS [Cyrillic Small Letter Ie], -- е
        NCHAR(0x0404) AS [Cyrillic Capital Letter E], -- Є
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0404) COLLATE Kazakh_90_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_90],-- <>
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0404) COLLATE Kazakh_100_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_100], -- =
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0404) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General],-- <>
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0404) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General_100]-- <>

-- case and accent -sensitive
SELECT  NCHAR(0x0435) AS [Cyrillic Small Letter Ie], -- е
        NCHAR(0x0454) AS [Cyrillic Small Letter E], -- є
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0454) COLLATE Kazakh_90_CS_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_90], -- <>
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0454) COLLATE Kazakh_100_CS_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_100], -- =
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0454) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General], -- <>
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0435) = NCHAR(0x0454) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General_100] -- <>
```

returns:

```
Cyrillic Small  Cyrillic Small Letter         Kazakh  Kazakh  Latin1_  Latin1_
Letter Ie       Abkhasian Che With Descender  _90     _100    General  General_100
е               ҿ                             =       =       =        <>


Cyrillic Small    Cyrillic Capital    Kazakh    Kazakh    Latin1_    Latin1_
Letter Ie         Letter E            _90       _100      General    General_100
е                 Є                   <>        =         <>         <>


Cyrillic Small    Cyrillic Small    Kazakh    Kazakh    Latin1_    Latin1_
Letter Ie         Letter E          _90       _100      General    General_100
е                 є                 <>        =         <>         <>
```

The Kazakh-specific overrides also cause the character "Cyrillic Small Letter Io" (U+0451) to no longer equate to its upper-case character:

```sql
-- Also messed up, just like Ie; accent-sensitive
SELECT  NCHAR(0x0451) AS [Cyrillic Small Letter Io], -- ё
        NCHAR(0x0401) AS [Cyrillic Capital Letter Io], -- Ё
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0451) = NCHAR(0x0401) COLLATE Kazakh_90_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_90],-- <>
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0451) = NCHAR(0x0401) COLLATE Kazakh_100_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Kazakh_100], -- <>
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0451) = NCHAR(0x0401) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General],-- =
        IIF(NCHAR(0x0451) = NCHAR(0x0401) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, '=', '<>') AS [Latin1_General_100]-- =
```

returns:

```
Cyrillic Small    Cyrillic Capital    Kazakh    Kazakh    Latin1_    Latin1_
Letter Io         Letter Io           _90       _100      General    General_100
ё                 Ё                   <>        <>        =          =
```

All of this behavior is a remnant of Microsoft's initial implementation of Unicode (way back in Windows NT 4.0!). Microsoft, to their credit, was an early adopter of Unicode, and this behavior *might* be how it was defined back in Unicode version 1.0. It's difficult to say for certain as it's not easy finding the original collation files for Unicode (I think version 2.1 was the earliest I could find). However, I can say from looking at the files provided by Microsoft, even though they updated the default sort weights and added characters and cultures across each of those files, some defintions, such as the Kazakh-specific overrides, were not updated until more recently. In fact, it's not until the "Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012" file (i.e. the second most recent set of definitions) that they fixed the Kazakh-specific overrides (and I assume others).

Hence, even though Windows in general (and possibly also .NET) handles Kazakh collations correctly (starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012), SQL Server collations are still stuck in the past. Meaning, there is no fix outside of a miracle that Microsoft updates these collations to a more recent version of Unicode. I do have an idea that I've been thinking of proposing to them for how to make it even better than a simple definition update, so perhaps I should go ahead and submit that (I will update this answer with the link once I have done that).

But for now, if you *really* need these two characters to equate in a case-insensitive Kazakh collation (and don't forget about "Cyrillic Small Letter Io" (U+0451)), you will have to do the `UPPER()` trick from your example (though I can't say for certain that this work-around won't cause any issues).

---

For more info on collations, Unicode, and encodings, please visit my site: [Collations.Info](https://Collations.Info/)